# Is $\alpha=3-\sqrt[5]{5}-\sqrt[5]{25}$ algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

How to determine whether the given real number $\alpha =3-\sqrt[5]{5}-\sqrt[5]{25}$ is algebraic or not. And, $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]=?$

Let $x=3-\sqrt[5]{5}-\sqrt[5]{25}$, 
\begin{align*}
& x = 3-\sqrt[5]{5}-\sqrt[5]{25}\\
\implies & (x-3)  = -\sqrt[5]{5}-\sqrt[5]{25}\\
\implies & (x-3)^5=(-\sqrt[5]{5}-\sqrt[5]{25})^5
\end{align*}
But, solving this is abit tedios process, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Each of the terms is algebraic, and the [field of algebraic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number_field) is closed under addition.

Comment: No, I tried this to determine the degree of the extension which is the degree of the minimal polynomial.

Comment: Why is the r.h.s expression an integer?

Comment: Scratch my previous comment. It is not an integer. I made a silly mistake (more morning coffee, please). Anyway, I would try to prove that A) $\alpha$ is irrational, B) observe that $\alpha$ is an element of $\Bbb{Q}(\root5\of5)$ and go with that.

Comment: So the extension degree should be 5, but I don't think it will be 5 (maybe I am wrong).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\alpha\pmatrix{1\\5^{1/5}\\5^{2/5}\\5^{3/5}\\5^{4/5}}
=\pmatrix{3&-1&-1&0&0\\0&3&-1&-1&0\\0&0&3&-1&-1\\-5&0&0&3&-1\\-5&-5&0&0&3}
\pmatrix{1\\5^{1/5}\\5^{2/5}\\5^{3/5}\\5^{4/5}}
$$
so that $\alpha$ is an eigenvalue of
$$\pmatrix{3&-1&-1&0&0\\0&3&-1&-1&0\\0&0&3&-1&-1\\-5&0&0&3&-1\\-5&-5&0&0&3}.
$$
This matrix has integer entries, and so its characteristic equation
has integer coefficients. Therefore $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer.

As $\alpha\in\Bbb Q(5^{1/5})$ and $\alpha\notin\Bbb Q$ and $|\Bbb Q(5^{1/5}):\Bbb Q|=5$ and $5$ is prime, then $\Bbb Q(\alpha)=\Bbb Q(5^{1/5})$.

Comment: This is a nice way of showing $\alpha$ is algebraic. Thanks.

Comment: Shark, how did you get the matrix?

Answer (score 3):

Since $X^5-5$ is $\mathbb Q$-irreducible (Eisenstein) it is the minimal polynomial of $r:=\sqrt [5] 5$ over $\mathbb Q$.
Hence the field $\mathbb Q(r)=\mathbb Q[r]\cong \mathbb Q[X]/\langle X^5-5\rangle $ is a $\mathbb Q$-vector space with basis $1,r,r^2,r^3,r^4$.
Obviously $\mathbb Q\subset \mathbb Q[\alpha] \subset \mathbb Q[r]$ and since $\alpha =3-r-r^2\notin \mathbb Q$, we have $\mathbb Q\varsubsetneq  \mathbb Q[\alpha] \subset \mathbb Q[r]$.
But the field $\mathbb Q[r]$ has degree $5$ over $\mathbb Q$, a *prime* number, so that its only non trivial subfield is itself and $\mathbb Q[\alpha] = \mathbb Q[r]$.   Thus  $$[\mathbb Q[\alpha]:\mathbb Q]==[\mathbb Q[r]:\mathbb Q]=5$$